# Public key verification always returns "Signature does not match"

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, keystore

I am trying to verify the public key of a certificate. The certificate has been imported into a keystore using this command:

```
keytool -importcert -file cert.cer -keystore kstore.jks -alias mycert -storepass changeit
```

This is the java code I use to verify the public key:

```
File keyStore = new File("kstore.jks");
String keyStorePassword = "changeit";
KeyStore ks = null;
try {
   ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
   ks.load(keyStore.toURI().toURL().openStream(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} 

try {
   Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("mycert");
   PublicKey pk = cert.getPublicKey();
   cert.verify(pk);
   //cert.verify(pk, "SunRsaSign");
   System.out.println("Keys verified");
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
   at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:446)
   at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:389)
   at VerifyEBXMLSignature.runIt3(VerifyEBXMLSignature.java:62)
   at VerifyEBXMLSignature.main(VerifyEBXMLSignature.java:41)
```

The certificate contains a public key and I do not have access to the private key.
Is it at all possible to verify the public key against this certificate that I import into a keystore? The public key comes from the certificate itself, so it should be correct.

What more should I look for with the certificate?

I just got some more iformation about the certificate: It is exported from the private key. Is there anything in that process that may have be done wrong?

Comment: Are you using self-signed certificates?

Comment: I believe the original certificate is self-signed. Howver, the public key certificate (that I am using) has been exported from the original.

Comment: The posted code only works if the certificate referenced by "mycert" is a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Does that mean that verifying the public key (as in: cert.verify(pk);) cannot be done on a public key certificate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing in the public key that you extracted from the certificate. You should be passing in the public key of the issuer's certificate to verify the signature.

So, as Robert pointed out in comments, your above code only works if it's a self-signed certificate (the certificate is signed with itself).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. I got the original certificate and it passes the verification without error.

Answer (score -2):

The public key verify method internally uses `X509` Certificate implementation.

So it can only verify those certificates which are generated as per `X509` standards.

For more info Visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509